# How to add Size and Hardware parameters in Load testing?

Tags: performance, jmeter, load, performance-testing, load-testing

My client has asked me to add below parameters in my load test result:

"How are we doing on performance testing? Do we have any benchmarks - Eg. PPR 8 Core 32 GB RAM  250

Concurrent Users - 50

Reports: min & min report size - xx kb)

If we haven’t carried out any such performance tests yet, can we plan for."

So, presently I'm only showing Response/elapsed time graph and Latency Graph in MS Excel, for up to 50 concurrent users.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxACg.png)

My question is how may I add the Size parameter in the results?

Also how shall I test on the Hardware benchmarks for Load test (eg. 8 Core 32 GB RAM)?

What more things shall I do in performance testing, my client doesn't looks satisfied with the performance test I'm running currently.

(I'm a newbie to performance testing, 3 months only with this domain)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you're downloading some report and the client wants to see correlation of response time and response size you can check out the following charts:

   - [Bytes Throughput Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/BytesThroughput)
   - [Response Times Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesOverTime)
2. With regards to measuring the hardware impact, you can collect it using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test), it can gather and plot more than 70 various [metrics](https://github.com/undera/perfmon-agent#supported-metrics) (CPU, Memory, Disk, Network, TCP, JMX and custom ones)

Comment: Thanks Dimitri, you know what you are helping me with every query with this project :D

Comment: Hi Dimitri,

I'm getting this error while running JMeter PerfMon

17:51:31 - ERROR: java.io.IOException: Agent is unreachable via TCP
17:51:33 - ERROR: java.io.IOException: Agent is unreachable via TCP

let me open a new ticket here on stack overflow for this if you can help with that ...
17:51:34 - ERROR: java.io.IOException: Agent is unreachable via TCP

Comment: opened a new stakcoverflow ticket for this issue 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66564859/jmeter-perfmon-having-issues

Comment: How these comments are related with the original question?