# JMeter PerfMon having issues

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I'm using PerfMon JMeter Plugin after referring this article
https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test

[image]

Getting this error on PerfMon, can someone help please. How shall I fix it ?

This is the image of the server agent
[image]

I'm running the test on localhost server, not sure ow to resolve this
ERROR: java.io.IOException: Agent is unreachable via TCP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that the referenced article mentions that you need to [pause the server agent process anywhere](https://superuser.com/questions/459609/what-does-it-do-exactly-if-i-click-in-the-window-of-cmd). Looking at this "Select" bit in your console window:

[image]

it appears that you have "selected" something in the terminal window where the server agent is running, it "pauses" the process.

It looks like a white rectangle:

[image]

so just perform a right mouse button click in the window and the server agent should continue running and you will see the metrics.

You might find [How to Monitor Server Resource Utilization with JMeter’s SSHMon Listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-monitor-server-resource-utilization-with-jmeters-sshmon-listener) article useful, this approach doesn't assume any server-side software installation so it may be more convenient